# Are Zerigo's claims to have instant update on their DNS service legitimate or just marketing word semantics?

Tags: domain-name-system, zerigo

Zerigo states on [their site](http://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns/instant-updates-low-ttls)

> **Instant updates**
>
> When you make a change to your DNS
> records, it takes a moment for them to
> replicate to all of the DNS servers.
> Until this happens, nobody can see the
> change.
>
> Zerigo's proprietary synchronization
> engine ensures this happens in mere
> seconds. We won't name names (to
> protect the guilty), but many
> providers take hours to perform
> updates. In our opinion, that's crazy
> and it's why we designed our system
> for much faster updates.

Are they really stating that their service is different from how DNS operates normally, or is this just stating that when you make a change they make sure it instantly removes any old cached records from their systems but doesn't do anything about other DNS servers?

Comment: It is not mere seconds though. I can take a couple minutes, but always less than 3 or 4. Speaking from personal experience with 75+ zones at Zerigo for a couple years now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true. It basically means that all updates you do to their DNY do sync to THEIR DNS (!) immediately (or close to real time). This is standard for good DNS providers - there is a push protocol that a DNS can sue to inform replicated slaves that a zone has changed. Normall DNS slaves (as most are in a typcial DNS farm) timeout on the data.

Sadly this is amrketing speak. Basically they push "normal practices" for a well managed DNS farm. Only a badly managed farm will not configure the slaves and master for a push if a change occurs on the master.

That said, this does NOT invalidate caces all over the internet. Point. They also dont claim that. if you read carefully waht they said - basically thy claim to immediately update, while some providers take hours to update THEIR OWN (i.e. those providers) servers. Crappy providers all around, pretty much.

Comment: I had figured it was word semantics for marketing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for them to be touching other people's DNS servers to remove their cached records.  It seems to just be marketing-speak for 'we update our DNS clusters quickly'